# Exception raised during rendering: addView(View, LayoutParams) is not supported in AdapterView (Details) Tip: Try to refresh the layout

Tags: android-studio, android-layout, android-studio-4.0

here is screenshots of my xml(activity) file + the preview that stays empty...

https://ibb.co/3d9BjYz
https://ibb.co/3CvTJKh

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of code, XML, or logs. Please post all text as text. That said, you cannot have anything inside a `<ListView>` in your layout. A `ListView`'s children must come from an `Adapter`. You need to (re)move the `<TextView>` that's there now.

Answer (score 0):

Please read AdapterView explanation in Android Documentation. Here is the explanation: "An AdapterView is a view whose children are determined by an Adapter."

You didn't share your Java code, but you need an Adapter to bind data and view. Please check getView method in your Adapter. Your problem should be related with the parent view in your Adapter class.

Comment: I have added the code on the links just below the description